Convert 0-1 integer linear program to quadratic form.
I am searching for a general conversion from 0-1 integer linear programs to (integer) quadratic programs. And I see this answer using a general example. https://qr.ae/psu9Wr. I checked the optimality is correct. But I don't know what theory or principle he used to do this, and whether the optimality can always hold. Can anyone help me with any keywords for such a technique? Thanks a lot!

Add the constraints $x(1-x)=0$ for every binary variable (or add $cx(1-x)$ as another term in the objective function, for some constant $c>0$), and you're good to go.

Thanks for the answer! Do you mean that relaxing $x$ from binary to continuous variable between 0 and 1, then applying the non-convex constraint $x(1-x)=0$? By doing this, the original integer linear program (ILP) becomes a continuous non-convex problem. In some solvers (such as Gurobi), the global optimality of an ILP can be reached given sufficient time. But for this continuous non-convex problem, the global optimality is not guaranteed. Is this making things worse? Thanks again!

@ShengzhiLai, your question talks about converting to an integer quadratic program.  It says nothing about convexity or making things worse/better.  We are a question-and-answer site, my purpose is to answer the question that was asked.

sorry for the misleading question. I was wondering how the method in the link I pasted worked. Because I cannot reformulate that problem as it was described. Anyway, I will ask another question precisely on this. Thanks!
